# RuntimeError: Can't resolve dependencies Django Groups with Users

Tags: django, django-models

Now I had a problem
`RuntimeError: Can't resolve dependencies` while running tests and after long debugging We found that a forigen key relationship is the problem
Yet we need this relation in our app

I have to get an owner relation to Django Groups

The models like that:

```
class UserAccount(AbstractUser):
    arabic_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True)
    parent = models.ForigenKey('self', null=True)


django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.add_to_class('owner', models.ForeignKey('users.UserAccount',
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              related_name='groups_created'
                              ))
```

As I need to define an owner to the groups as I have my specific hierarchy system for users so no one can see others groups

So what Can I do?

---

### Update - Solution

```
class UserAccount(AbstractUser):
        arabic_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True)
        hierarchy_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()


django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.add_to_class('hierarchy_id', models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True))

#script populate hierarchy 
h_id=0
for user in users:
    if user.is_parent:
         then user.hierar...... = h_id
```

and so on.. I populated hierarchy ID instead of relation

Thanks

Comment: is UserAccount set as your AUTH_USER_MODEL?

Comment: Yes no problem a this , the problem in circular dependency

Comment: I found the solution Thanks so much, I wish you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found you can do a circular dependency without your knowledge, in case you do a relation and migrate it then do the reverse relation after a while then migrate it , it will not clash but when both migrated instantly in tests for example it will clash. so I tried this solution and tested, after a year from asking the question, it is working well.

```
class UserAccount(AbstractUser):
    arabic_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True)
    hierarchy_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

django.contrib.auth.models import Group

Group.add_to_class('hierarchy_id', models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True))

#script populate hierarchy 
h_id=0
for user in users:
    if user.is_parent:
         then user.hierar...... = h_id
```